# Hive not updating field values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a user box where I store some data about the user.
In the `main.dart` file, I am registering and opening the `UserDBAdapter`

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserDBAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<UserDB>('users');
  return runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
```

In my `Bloc`, I have a function which logins the user and then saves `true` in the `isLoggedIn` field of the `user`

```
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  UserDB user = UserDB();
  final usersBox = Hive.box<UserDB>('users');
  UserRepository userRepository;

  UserBloc(this.userRepository) : super(UserInitial()) {
    createUser();
    verifyUser();
    loginUser();
    logoutUser();
    usersBox.put('user', user);
 }
   Future<void> loginUser() async {
    return on<LoginUser>((event, emit) async {
      emit(UserLoading());
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      try {
        final result = await userRepository.login(
          event.email,
          event.password,
        );
        if (result['success'] == false) {
          emit(UserError(result['message']));
        } else {
          emit(
            UserLoggedIn(),
          );
          user.isLoggedIn = true; // I set it to true here
          user.token = result['token'];
          user.save(); // Then I save it here. which means the new changes is persisted in the local storage
        }
      } catch (error) {
        emit(
          UserError(
            error.toString(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

But my point is that, when I try hot reloading the app, it sends me to the login screen instead of the `HomeScreen()`

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    if (Hive.box<UserDB>('users').get('user') == null) {
      print('empty'); // This does not print, that means I have a user in the local storage
      Hive.box<UserDB>('users').put(
        'user',
        UserDB(isVerified: false, isLoggedIn: false),
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userDB = Hive.box<UserDB>('users').get('user')!;
    print(userDB.isLoggedIn); // Here prints false instead of true
    if (userDB.isLoggedIn) {
      return const NavigationScreen();
    } else if (userDB.isVerified && !userDB.isLoggedIn) {
      return AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: const SplashScreen(),
        duration: 4000,
        nextScreen: const LoginSignUpSwitch(),
      );
    } else {
      return AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: const SplashScreen(),
        duration: 4000,
        nextScreen: const WelcomeScreen(),
      );
    }
  }
```

Below is the UserDB class

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class UserDB extends HiveObject {
  UserDB({
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.isVerified = false,
    this.isLoggedIn = false,
    this.token,
  });
  // NAME (0)
  @HiveField(0)
  String? name;

//EMAIL(1)
  @HiveField(1)
  String? email;

//IS-VERIFIED(2)
  @HiveField(2, defaultValue: false)
  bool isVerified;

//IS-LOGGEDIN(3)
  @HiveField(3, defaultValue: false)
  bool isLoggedIn;

//TOKEN(4)
  @HiveField(4)
  String? token;
}
```

*NB: I am printing the value of the isLoggedIn in the HomeScreen and it prints true*

```
final userDB = Hive.box<UserDB>('users').get('user');
    print(userDB!.isLoggedIn); // Prints true here
```

Comment: can you share your UserDB class

Comment: I have included it in the question